# Hadoop map-reducer is not writing any output

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am working on a three node Hadoop mapreduce problem that is intended to take a 200,000 line `input.csv` file with Dates and Point Values as headers (gist of 25 line sample data: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PatMulvihill/63effd90411efe858330b54a4111fadb/raw/4033695ba5ca2f439cfd1512358425643807d83b/input.csv).  The program should find any Point Value that isn't the following values: `200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1600, or 2000`.  That point value should be the value.  The key should be the year from the date in the value before that point value.  For instance, if we have the data 
`2000-05-25,400
2001-10-12, 650
2001-04-09, 700`
 The key-value pairs that should be sent to the reducer are `<2001, 650>` and `<2001, 700>`.  The reducer should then take the average of all values in each given year, and write those key-value pairs to the hdfs `/out` path I have specified.  The program compiles fine, but never actually writes anything to output.  I want to know why and what I can do to fix it.

The full code is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class JeopardyMR {

public static class SplitterMapper extends Mapper <Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void map (Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Convert the CSVString (of type Text) to a string
        String CSVString = value.toString();
        // Split the string at each comma, creating an ArrayList with the different attributes in each index.
        // Sometimes the questions will be split into multiple elements because they contain commas, but for the
        // way we will be parsing the CSV's, it doesn't matter.
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(CSVString.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        // Loop through all the elements in the CSV
        // Start i at 3 to ensure that you do not parse a point value that has a year absent from the data set.
        // We can end the loop at items.size() w/o truncating the last 3 items because if we have a point value, we know
        // that the corresponding year is in the items before it, not after it.
        // We will miss 1 or 2 data points because of this, but it shouldn't matter too much because of the magnitude of our data set
        // and the fact that a value has a low probability of actually being a daily double wager.
        for (int i = 3; i < items.size(); i++) {
            // We want a String version of the item that is being evaluated so that we can see if it matches the regex
            String item = items.get(i);
            if (item.matches("^\\d{4}\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$")) {
                // Make sure that we don't get an out of bounds error when trying to access the next item
                if (i + 1 >= items.size()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    // the wagerStr should always be the item after a valid air date
                    String wagerStr = items.get(i + 1);
                    int wager = Integer.parseInt(wagerStr);
                    // if a wager isn't the following values, assume that is a daily double wager
                    if (wager != 200 && wager != 400 && wager != 600 && wager != 800 && wager != 1000 && wager != 1200 && wager != 1600 && wager != 2000) {
                        // if we know that a point value of a question is in fact a daily double wager, find the year that the daily double happened
                        // the year will always be the first 4 digits of a valid date formatted YYYY-MM-DD
                        char[] airDateChars = item.toCharArray();
                        String year = "" + airDateChars[0] + airDateChars[1] + airDateChars[2] + airDateChars[3];

                        // output the follow key-value pair: <year, wager>
                        context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(wager));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer <Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    public void reduce (Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0, count = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
            count++;
        }
        int avg = sum / count;
        result.set(avg);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "jeopardy daily double wagers by year");
    job.setJarByClass(JeopardyMR.class);
    job.setMapperClass(SplitterMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

The successful compile terminal output can be found here: https://gist.github.com/PatMulvihill/40b3207fe8af8de0b91afde61305b187

I am very new to Hadoop map-reduce, and I am probably making a very silly mistake.  I based this code off the code found here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Please let me know if I am missing any useful information.  Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Try simplifying the example (do not do any filtering) to check if the data will be written.

Comment: You can check a few things to see where the problem is: is it that you don't read anything? Check the map input records counter. If it's zero, check the input path.  Is it that you don't write anything from the mapper (probably yes)? Check the map output records counter. Try to print something inside the if that checks for pattern matches and see if it's printed

Comment: @vefthym I checked the map input records counter and it is equal to the amount of input records, which is to be expected.  I confirmed that the input path is correct by formatting and re-adding the input file to the hdfs.  I think my issue is that I don't write anything from the mapper to the reducer.  Map output records counter is 0, as is bytes written.  Here is the output of terminal messages when my program compiles successfully: https://gist.github.com/PatMulvihill/40b3207fe8af8de0b91afde61305b187

Answer (score 1):

I check and think items.size() is two. as you know input of map is lines of files and map task executed map function for each line. once each line splited by semicolon the size of items become 2 and next for executed when items size bigger than 3.
You can check map output write byte to see any data write or not.
EDIT : 
replace map code with this :

```
public void map (Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String CSVString = value.toString();
        String[] yearsValue =  CSVString.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        if(yearsValue.length == 2){
            int wager = Integer.parseInt(yearsValue[1]);
            if (wager != 200 && wager != 400 && wager != 600 && wager != 800 && wager != 1000 && wager != 1200 && wager != 1600 && wager != 2000) {
                char[] airDateChars = yearsValue[0].toCharArray();
                String year = "" + airDateChars[0] + airDateChars[1] + airDateChars[2] + airDateChars[3];
                context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(wager));

            }
        }else{
            System.out.println(CSVString);
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you @vahid. I retracted my "not-an-answer" flag and downvote. However, your answer is still wrong, since using the combiner in this case is not only correct, but also a very good practice. Please, consider deleting this part of your answer.

Comment: @vahid Any idea why `items.size()` would only be two?  My understanding is that when I am casting the `values` parameter to a String, I am taking all the values at making one giant String that contains all the input that has been given to that specific node.  Am I misunderstanding something? Also, how do you determine that `items.size()` is two?  My prints don't work on hadoop applications and they don't end up in the log files they are supposed to.

Comment: @Pat Mulvihill we have two concept for map: 1- map task 2- map function. Mapreduce base on configuration partiton input data and give it to map task then map task partion input data base on new line and give each line to map function. You write map function not map task.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this issue by converting my `.csv` file to a `.txt` file.  That isn't a real *solution* to the problem, but it is what made my code work and now I can move on to understanding why it was an issue.  Plus, this might help someone in the future!